# Ubuntu caffe installation error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudnn

Tags: linux, ubuntu, caffe

I am trying to install caffe on my ubuntu 14.04 and I follow these instructions:  http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html#compilation

In short: i get this error:   **/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudnn**, when trying to compile using "make all" like it says on the instructions on the caffe website.

background:
While installing, I got to the part of **compilation**  and when I tried "make all" it gave me an error of: "cannot find cudnn.h file" - **I solved it** by downloading that file from nvidia website and copying it to /usr/local/cuda-8.0/include. Then I tried "make all" one more time and I got this recent error:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudnn
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1

Please help

Comment: Where is your `libcudnn.so`?  If it's not installed, install it and its headers. Otherwise, find its directory, add it (directory name) in `/etc/ld.so.conf` and execute `ldconfig`. Then try to make again.

Comment: `libcudnn.so`: Ubuntu 17.04 has **libcaffe-cuda-dev**, `caffe-cuda` etc.   http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=caffe&searchon=names , not available for 14.04,  16.04 . ... CUDA : the Nvidia website .

Comment: @KnudLarsen OP asks about Ubuntu **14.04**.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody I managed to solve it:
the solution that worked for me was to use the libraries I downloaded and copy their content to my existing library of that same name:
1. download the cuDNN v6.0 library for **linux** (not ubuntu or anything else)
2. extract.
3. copy "cudnn.h" to /usr/local/cuda-8.0/include using terminal and sudo.
4. copy lib64's content(what you just downloaded) to /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/ using terminal and sudo.

now try "make all -j8" and it should work :)